# Appending charactes to a string when duplicate found

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, duplicates

Say i have a table of IDs, Names and a field to flag an update as follows:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| ID | Name  | Update? |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | A     | y       |
|  2 | B     | y       |
|  3 | xxB   |         |
|  4 | C     |         |
|  5 | D     | y       |
|  6 | xxD   |         |
|  7 | xxxD  |         |
|  8 | E     |         |
+----+-------+---------+
```

The 'update' is to append an 'xx' to the name, however there cannot be duplicate names in the table so i'd like to append an additional 'x' to any duplicates found. So for this one the table would update to this:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| ID | Name  | Update? |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | xxA   |         |
|  2 | xxB   |         |
|  3 | xxxB  |         |
|  4 | C     |         |
|  5 | xxD   |         |
|  6 | xxxD  |         |
|  7 | xxxxD |         |
|  8 | E     |         |
+----+-------+---------+
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this? Its the updating of duplicates that would occur with the initial update that i'm stuck on, and i'm not sure how easy it would be to have it check back on and update all the levels of duplication, eg A is no duplicate, B is 1 level, D is 2 levels etc.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: what you exacty want when you want A to XXA then E also XXE ..but you have mentioned as E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5b00/1/0)

```
WITH CteUpdate AS(
    SELECT *, 
        base = REPLACE(Name, 'x', ''),
        xxName = REPLICATE('x', 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                        PARTITION BY REPLACE(Name, 'x', '') 
                        ORDER BY ID
                    ) + 1
                ) + REPLACE(Name, 'x', '')
    FROM TestData
    WHERE
        REPLACE(Name, 'x', '') IN(
            SELECT Name FROM TestData WHERE [Update] = 1
        )
)
UPDATE CteUpdate 
    SET Name = xxName
        , [Update] = 0
```

**Result**:

```
ID          Name       Update
----------- ---------- ------
1           xxA        0
2           xxB        0
3           xxxB       0
4           C          0
5           xxD        0
6           xxxD       0
7           xxxxD      0
8           E          0
```

---

First, you want to get all rows that have the same base `Name` (the `Name` minus the `xx`s) with those rows with `Update = 1`. To get the base `Name`, just replace `x` with `''`:

```
SELECT *, 
    base = REPLACE(Name, 'x', '')
FROM TestData
WHERE
    REPLACE(Name, 'x', '') IN(
        SELECT Name FROM TestData WHERE [Update] = 1
    )
```

The result of the above will be:

```
ID          Name       Update base
----------- ---------- ------ ------
1           A          1      A
2           B          1      B
3           xxB        0      B
5           D          1      D
6           xxD        0      D
7           xxxD       0      D
```

Then, you want to use `ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY base ORDER BY ID)`. The resulting `ROW_NUMBER + 1` will be the number of `x`s to be added on the `base`

```
WITH CteUpdate AS(
    SELECT *, 
        base = CAST(REPLACE(Name, 'x', '') AS VARCHAR(1))
    FROM TestData
    WHERE
        REPLACE(Name, 'x', '') IN(
            SELECT Name FROM TestData WHERE [Update] = 1
        )
)
SELECT
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY base ORDER BY ID),
    xxName = REPLICATE('x', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY base ORDER BY ID) + 1) + base
FROM CteUpdate
```

The result of the query above will be:

```
ID          Name       Update base   RN    xxName
----------- ---------- ------ ------ ----- ---------
1           A          1      A      1     xxA
2           B          1      B      1     xxB
3           xxB        0      B      2     xxxB
5           D          1      D      1     xxD
6           xxD        0      D      2     xxxD
7           xxxD       0      D      3     xxxxD
```

The `xxName` will now be the updated `Name`.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask any question.